# How to end the current loop(but not the whole while statement) in PHP?

Tags: php, while-loop

in `While()`,How to skip the following nested statements and execute next loop of the `while()` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply `continue;`

Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: And if you want to stop a while loop, use break!
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php